# removing comma and adding the values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

salescopy['Number_of_Products'] = salescopy['Number_of_Products'].str.replace(',', '')

number of products is a column in salescopy dataset

I tried to use the above code it removes commas in column and but i need   to remove comma and adding all the values to a single value

say ex :1,1,1,1 = 1111= (4)it should remove the commas and add them all

you can refer to the image below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Firstly replace the 'undefined' value present in your **'Number_of_Products'** column by `nan` by using `replace()` method:

```
df['Number_of_Products']=df['Number_of_Products'].replace('undefined',np.nan,regex=True)
```

Finally make use of `apply()` and `eval()` method:

```
df['Number_of_Products']=df['Number_of_Products'].fillna(0).replace(',','+',regex=True).apply(pd.eval)
```

Now if you want those missing values(`nan`) back(in any senerio) in your dataframe then:

```
df['Number_of_Products']=df['Number_of_Products'].replace(0,np.nan,regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but I forgot to mention a point about dataset, number products column as few cells has a single-digit when python see those single values it's treating as nan values how to solve this case

Comment: It is not converting single values to `NaN`...I am using pandas version `1.2.2`

Comment: I'm using 3.8.3 version for which its treating as Nan 

can you help me to solve this

Comment: i tried all the possible ways but its not working

Comment: what is your pandas version?  use this: `pandas.__version__` or `pd.__version__` for finding out

Comment: i checked myself and im working on Jupiter notebook it showed me 3.8.3 version

Comment: you are checking python version not pandas version...as pandas latest version is `1.2.3` so how you can get `3.8.3` so that's your python version

Comment: sorry its '1.0.5' version

Comment: then kindly update/upgrade your pandas package **:)**

Comment: hi Anurag it's my mail id :vishnuvarkala19@gmail.com can we get in touch

Comment: hi anurag, updated the pandas but im getting out as below format 

[1 ,1 ,1 ,1] not working

Comment: It's working fine on my side.....make changes in your question please add how your dataframe looks like(as text) and what code you are using and what error/output you are getting

Comment: or upload your csv file/datasource on gdrive ,ondrive or any other cloud storage service **if it's not confidential data/not contains any personal data** and add that link to your question

Comment: I'm unable to post pictures here... I tried already dataset is bit confidential actually

if your we can connect over email

Answer (score 0):

Just map `eval()` to all elements in Series

```py
salescopy['sum'] = salescopy['Number_of_Products'].str.replace(',', '+').map(eval)
salescopy['Number_of_Products'] = salescopy['Number_of_Products'].str.replace('+', '.')
```

You can also split the string and sum them together.

```py
salescopy['sum'] = salescopy['Number_of_Products'].map(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split(','))))
```